# How to maintain the session timeout in wso2as 5.0.0 and wso2 Esb 4.5.1 version?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2as 5.0.0 application server but after few seconds they automatically redirect the logine page the same issues happening wso2 ESB 4.5.1 version also.. please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: redirect the login page to where?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF
2. Change the session-timeout value in web.xml file
3. Change session-timeout value to as you want